# What's the meaning of "I'd say"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sarcasm

In a discussion on closets, person A posted a picture of his closet and person B made a comment on it:

> Cowboy boots in the north WTF,
>   and who needs that many hats?

Person A then replies:

> I've cleaned it up since. Lots of leftover questionable clothes and shoes from my younger days...
>
> The cowboy boots stayed though because they're f-ing awesome.

Person B then says:

> I'd say. I see that tennis ball yellow piece of clothing there :puke:

In person B's last comment, when he said "I'd say", what does that mean? I know that *I'd* means *I would*, but what does *say* mean? Does he mean he agrees with person A's comment "Lots of leftover questionable clothes and shoes from my younger days..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's short for:

> I would say so [as well].

*say* has it's normal meaning: to communicate.

In other words it means *I agree with you.*

There's two possible thing they could be agreeing with:
1 that the cowboy boots are f-in' awesome.
2 that there was lots of questionable clothing leftover.

It's likely that they mean the latter since they follow it up with a comment about the questionable nature of the tennis ball yellow piece.  But they could be trying to remain intentionally ambiguous because they might think the boots should go as well.

Comment: Where I'm from, it's usually used as emphatic agreement, something like "Wow, definitely!"

Answer (score 2):

"I'll say" is an alternate expression, short for "I will say so as well."  Different areas typically use one or the other.